# Can you target a creature with my creatures enter the battlefield ability if they both enter the battlefield at the same time?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a single copy of [Meteor Golem](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMeteor%20Golem%5d) in my sideboard to go against [Show and Tell](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bShow%20and%20Tell%5d) decks, but I am wondering if my opponent show and tells their [Emrakul, the Aeons Torn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEmrakul%2c%20the%20Aeons%20Torn%5d), can I show my Meteor Golem, target it and destroy their Emrakul?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [show and tell, gilded drake and primeval titan](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/14737/show-and-tell-gilded-drake-and-primeval-titan)

Comment: I don't see this as a duplicate; that other question is about who is the controller of an ability; not what creatures are valid targets for an ability.

Comment: It's closer to [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/14735/show-and-tell-and-permanents-that-target-other-permanents?rq=1); but I still don't think it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can do this.

All creatures will enter the battlefield at the same time; but even if they didn't that wouldn't matter here. Meteor Golem's triggered ability is only put on the stack after the Show and Tell is finished fully resolving.

> 603.3. Once an ability has triggered, its controller puts it on the stack as an object that’s not a card the next time a player would receive priority.

and

> 116.3b The active player receives priority after a spell or ability (other than a mana ability) resolves.

So you do not need to choose targets for Meteor Golem's ability until Show and Tell is done resolving; and all chosen permanents are on the battlefield.

However, as pointed out by @John in a comment; all choices will be revealed simultaneously, so you cannot "respond" to your opponent's choice of Emrakul by choosing Meteor Golem. You would have already had to make your choice before you know your opponent's choice.

From the Gatherer rulings on Show and Tell:

> The current player chooses first, then each other player chooses in turn order. **A player does not have to reveal the chosen card**, so long as it is clear *which* card was chosen. After all choices are made, **the cards are put onto the battlefield simultaneously**.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, creatures that enter the battlefield at the same time "see each other" for the purposes of "enters the battlefield" triggered abilities like the one on Meteor Golem.

However, it is important to note that not all abilities that say "enters the battlefield" are triggered abilities like this one. If an ability says "When [something] enters the battlefield...", like on Meteor Golem, it is a triggered ability. But if it just says "[Something] enters the battlefield..." or "As [something] enters the battlefield...", like on [Clone](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bClone%5d) or [Canker Abomination](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCanker%20Abomination%5d), it is a replacement effect and does not interact with permanents that enter the battlefield at the same time.

Comment: Is it worth pointing out that in show and tell, you don't *know* your opponent chose Emrakul, you just know they chose a card?  i.e. choices are revealed simultaneously.

Comment: Seeing each other enter the battlefield isn't actually relevant here; that generally pertains to situations such as 2 Soul's Attendants entering at the same time. In this case, Meteor Golem just triggers like normal; what is relevant is that by the time the trigger is put on the stack (and targets are chosen); all Show and Tell creatures are on the battlefield.

Comment: I agree with Gendolkari. Even if these two creatures didn't see each other enter, the result would be the same. Consider a card that reads, "You put a creature card from your hand onto the battlefield. Target opponent puts a creature card from his or her hand onto the battlefield." In that case the opponent's creature would not see your creature enter, but would still be able to target it with any triggered abilities.